# How to fix ostream_iterator conversion problem?

Tags: c++

I was studying ' unique_copy( forwrdIt first,forwrdIt last, forwrdIt result) ' and i tried to pass result as : 'ostream_iterator(cout, " ") ' but it threw an error 'no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::ostream_iterator’ to ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >&&'. i can make another vector and then i can insert it's iterator. Why so?

i can make another vector and then i can insert it's begin() iterator. Why so?

```
vector<int> v = {1,2,3,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,8,1,1};
vector<int>::iterator ip;
    ip = unique_copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ","));
```

1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at documentation for the [`std::unique_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy) algorithm it shows the function return type is the same as the destination iterator type.

The algorithm destination is a `std::ostream_iterator<int>` and you're trying to assign the returned iterator to a `std::vector<int>::iterator`. The error is due to the type mismatch.

The code will compile if you remove the assignment and just call the algorithm.

```
vector<int> v = {1,2,3,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,8,1,1};
unique_copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ","));
```